# Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Count returns 1 even when no document is opened

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Count returns 1 even when no document is opened. Bellow the code returns 1 before creating new document:

```
private void Ribbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

MessageBox.Show($"Document count {Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Count}");

    }
```

Comment: After your add-in is started, do you see an empty document displayed in Word?

Comment: No. if I click on word application it launches home screen to choose template to create new doc or open an existing doc.

Comment: 1) Which version of Word is involved? 2) Once you exit the "home screen" is there a document displayed? Note that by default Word *always* presents a document. If a document is not opened, Word generates a new one, by default. That's why `Documents.Count` will return `1`. Test it in the interface - try to get Word to show you know document when it's started (and you've left the "home screen").

Comment: Office 365.
Basically I want to verify whether is there an activeDocument present by checking documents count in order to avoid COM exception(when you tried to access ActiveDocument on Ribbon_Load ).

Comment: I think everyone here is telling you that there ***will*** be a Document...

Answer (score 0):

The [Documents.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.count) property returns an integer that represents the number of documents in the collection. It seems a new document is created each time you start Word.

Comment: Basically I want to verify whether is there an activeDocument present by checking documents count in order to avoid COM exception(when you tried to access ActiveDocument on Ribbon_Load ).